# tika returning incorrect line of text for pdf with lots of tables

Tags: apache-tika

I am using tika to extract text from a pdf file that has lot of tables.

```
java -jar tika-app-0.9.jar -t https://s3.amazonaws.com/centraldoc/alg1.pdf
```

It is returning some invalid text and sometimes it is trimming white space between 2 words; for example it returns 
"qu inakli fmyathematical ideas to the real world" instead of  "Link mathematical ideas to the real world".

Is there a way to minimize this kind of error? or is there another library that  I can use? Does it make sense to use OCR to process these kind of pdf.

Comment: Have you tried with a recent nightly build of Tika? There have been a few bugs like that fixed since 0.9 that will be in 1.0 (due soon!)

Comment: Thanks. Do you know where I can get the nightly build for 1.0 ? I did not see it in http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tika/branches/

Comment: Tika 1.0 is being developed from [trunk](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tika/trunk). You can either do a svn checkout from there and build with maven, or grab tika-app.jar from the [snapsot repository](https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots-group/org/apache/tika/tika-app/1.0-SNAPSHOT/)

Comment: Thanks Gagravarr, I tested with jar file from the snapshot repository. It is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to control order when using PDFBox parser: `PDFTextStripper` has a flag that controls the order of lines in the document. By default (in PDFBox) it's set to false for performance reasons (no order preserved), but Tika changed its behavior between releases switching this flag on and off.

More details exactly on this problem in my blog [Extracting text from PDF files with Apache Tika 0.9 (and PDFBox under the hood)](http://novyden.blogspot.com/2011/06/extracting-text-from-pdf-files-with.html).

Answer (score 2):

To get text from PDF to display in the right order, I had to set the SortByPosition flag to true... (tika-app-1.19.jar)

```
                    BodyContentHandler handler   = new BodyContentHandler();
                    Metadata           metadata  = new Metadata();
                    ParseContext       context   = new ParseContext();
                    PDFParser          pdfParser = new PDFParser();

                    PDFParserConfig config = pdfParser.getPDFParserConfig();
                    config.setSortByPosition(true); // needed for text in correct order
                    pdfParser.setPDFParserConfig(config);

                    pdfParser.parse(is, handler, metadata, context);
```